# Linux: How can two USB root hubs have the same iSerial?

Tags: linux, usb

I recently needed to reset part of my USB subsystem because an external HDD suddenly went unavailable, and plugging it out and back in didn't help. For the reset procedure, I followed this documentation:
https://www.linux.org/threads/resetting-the-usb-subsystem.10404/

**The TL;DR of that documentation is:**
I need to echo the *iSerial* of the dysfunctional root hub to
**/sys/bus/pci/drivers/xhci_hcd/unbind**
and then to
**/sys/bus/pci/drivers/xhci_hcd/bind**

According to `lsusb -t`, I have six root hubs. However, when I've tried to determine the *iSerial* that I need for the *unbind* and *bind* actions, I've found out that two of the root hubs have the same:

```
root@TuxServer:~# lsusb -s 001:001 -v | grep -F iSerial
  iSerial 1 0000:02:00.0
root@TuxServer:~# lsusb -s 005:001 -v | grep -F iSerial
  iSerial 1 0000:02:00.0
```

This is kind of strange, because 001:001 is USB 2, and 005:001 is USB 3. And it's a problem, because when I try to unbind/bind 005:001, I've noticed that it happens on 001:001 instead. I can tell this because my keyboard and mouse are connected to 001:001, both are illuminated and the lights went out for a second. Fortunately these input devices worked normally after the reset, so I wasn't locked out of my PC :-)

What I need to know is:

- How can two USB root hubs have the same iSerial?
- How can I ensure the reset happens on 005:001?

My mainboad is a Gigabyte Aorus Gaming x470 (AMD Ryzen Generation 2 platform).
My Linux distribution is Arch Linux.